# Unable to find modules when routing Dart Angular Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, module, routes, dart, angular-dart

I have been following the [Dart Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/). I made it to part 5, where routing is taught. But I got stuck at the section where the [router is made available](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5#make-the-router-available). I typed out the code, but it does not build. I get the following error:

```
[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart:
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'package:angular_tour_of_heroes/app_component.template.dart' as ng;` from angular_app|web/main.template.dart at 10:1
`import 'package:angular_tour_of_heroes/app_component.template.dart' as ng;` from angular_app|web/main.dart at 3:1
```

To fix the error I have tried:

- Copy-pasting the code from the website.
- Making sure my `pubspec.yaml` is correct.
- Re-running `pub get` as well as running `pub upgrade`.
- Continuing the tutorial to see if the error is fixed later on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I haven't done the tutorial, but app_component is a file that is created earlier in the tutorial. `angular_tour_of_heroes` is the package name used in the example.

So for your own tutorial you would want to use:

```
import 'package:USE_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
```

Where you replace `USE_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` with the name that is in the `pubspec.yaml` file under `name: USE_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`

Comment: That did it. Thank you.